# FTP Download with design patterns in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, ftp

I have to do ftp download process
1) Check ftp files in each intervals
2) If any files have placed in ftp check whether file has completely uploaded in ftp or else check after some time(Here I'm planning to use observer design pattern)
3)Once file is completely placed, By using one of the BlockingQueue will start download.(please suggest which blocking queue should be used)
4)And if download is stopped because of some issue resume stopped one.

There can be multiple files, that also downloaded parallely
Please help in the above scenario with right design patterns and steps

Comment: That's really a nice question ,but its too broad.Try mentioning the starters ,like how you are approaching the problem with some programming concept.

Comment: I've mentioned for second condition I'm using observer pattern, but is it really required? because there is only one user requesting multiple times for files. and second doubt is here multiple files will be available in BlockingQueue, so is it possible to download multiple files at a time, If possible which type of blockingQueue will be easier?